# Fix less compilation on background position property

Tags: css, less

I have a problem since I went from less v1.7.0 to v1.7.5 less. I do not know for what reason but for this line:

```
.test {
     background: url("../img/arrow.png") no-repeat scroll right 14px top 18px transparent;
}
```

In the 1.7.0 release less left me this line as well, so that's good. But in the 1.7.5 release me less compiles as follows:

```
.test {
    background:url(../img/arrow.png) right 14px no-repeat
}
```

And so I lost my properties for the positioning of my background..

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Hm... It looks like they added parsing and removal of default values, i.e. `scroll` and `transparent` are filtered out. Then only the CSS 2 background positioning seems to be allowed, not the CSS 3 positioning...

Comment: Well, it's not really Less that removes those properties but `clean-css` which you seem to compile with...

Comment: I use gulp task to compile my less files. `gulp.src('files.css or less')
            .pipe(plumber())
            .pipe(gulpIf('*.less', less()))
            .pipe(concat(key + '.css'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('static/css'))
            .pipe(minifyCss({ keepSpecialComments: 0}))
            .pipe(concat('dest.css'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('static/css'));`

Comment: The `minifyCss` task is the `clean-css` one.

Comment: If i remove minifyCss command, so that's good. I add noAdvanced params for fixed it. thanks

Comment: You can add this solution as an answer I guess.